# How to use ' CastCompanionLibrary-android ' with MediaRouteButton with FragmentActivity

Tags: android, chromecast

I am working on integrating `Google Chromecast` in one of my `Android` application. For that I am referring to [Google Cast](https://github.com/googlecast/) examples.

I am using [CastCompanionLibrary-android - CCL](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android) and to understand how to use it I am referring to [Cast videos sample](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android). However this sample shows how to use cast button with `ActionBar`.

My question is, how to use this library if I have to use `MediaRouteButton` in my custom layout? At which places I have to make the changes?

My activity extends `FragmentActivity`.

**Note:** I did go through the pdf document provided with the library, however did not find much info on how to use library with `MediaRouteButton`.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE :**

Step 1 : I am getting a `VideoCastManager` instance.

Step 2 : I am getting the MediaRouteButton from my custom layout and adding it to `VideoCastManager` instance.

Step 3 : Implementing `onCastDeviceDetected()`,`onCastAvailabilityChanged()`,`onApplicationConnected()`, `onApplicationDisconnected()` and `onDisconnected()` methods of `VideoCastConsumerImpl` listener methods. Then adding this listener to `VideoCastManager` instance.

Step 4 : In `onApplicationConnected()`, I am calling `loadRemoteMedia()` by passing the current position of seekbar.

But it is not working. The video casting never starts.

**UPDATE 2 :**

Following are the logs I get when I try the Cast url in Cast video sample application.

> Application State :"Loaded.Started.Ready"
>
> Session Count:"2"
>
> Media Element State: "Stalled"
>
> Cast Receiver Manager Message:"Sender Connected: { OTHER DATA}"
>
> Media Manager Message: "LOAD {OTHER DATA} "
>
> Media Protocol : "m3u8" // my video is with m3u8 extention

And following are the logs I get when I try the Cast url in my application.

> Application State :"Loaded.Started.Ready"
>
> Session Count:"1"
>
> Media Element State:
>
> Cast Receiver Manager Message:"Sender Connected: { OTHER DATA}"
>
> Media Manager Message: "GET STATUS {OTHER DATA} "
>
> Media Protocol : Unknown

**UPDATE 3**
BaseCastManager Tag:

> D/ccl_BaseCastManager(2974): [v1.8] acquiring a connection to Google
> Play services for "Chromecast" (941cb5ec30f65c2082b67fd7c5df0b03)
>
> D/ccl_BaseCastManager(2974): [v1.8] onConnected() reached with prior
> suspension: false
>
> D/ccl_BaseCastManager(2974): [v1.8] launchApp() is
> called D/ccl_BaseCastManager(2974): [v1.8] Launching app
>
> D/ccl_BaseCastManager(2974): [v1.8] launchApplication() -> success result
>
> D/ccl_BaseCastManager(2974): [v1.8] Successfully added the new
> BaseCastConsumer listener
> om.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService$2@429998a8

VideoCastManager Tag:

> D/ccl_VideoCastManager(2974): [v1.8] onApplicationStatusChanged()
> reached: Chromecast Home Screen
>
> D/ccl_VideoCastManager(2974): [v1.8] onVolumeChanged() reached
>
> D/ccl_VideoCastManager(2974): [v1.8] onApplicationStatusChanged() reached: null
>
> D/ccl_VideoCastManager(2974): [v1.8] onApplicationConnected() reached
> with sessionId: B71F7618-1516-5F6C-D795-EF32FD0BF5E2, and
> mReconnectionStatus=INACTIVE
>
> D/ccl_VideoCastManager(2974): [v1.8] startNotificationService()
>
> D/ccl_VideoCastManager(2974): [v1.8] attachMedia()
>
> D/ccl_VideoCastManager(2974): [v1.8] Registering MediaChannel namespace
>
> D/ccl_VideoCastManager(2974): [v1.8] onApplicationStatusChanged() reached: Ready to play
>
> D/ccl_VideoCastManager(2974): [v1.8] Successfully added the new CastConsumer listener
> om.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService$2@429998a8
>
> D/ccl_VideoCastManager(2974): [v1.8] RemoteMediaPlayer::onStatusUpdated() is reached
>
> D/ccl_VideoCastManager(2974): [v1.8] onRemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdated() reached
>
> D/ccl_VideoCastManager(2974): [v1.8] mApiClient or mRemoteMediaPlayer is null, so will not > proceed
>
> D/ccl_VideoCastManager(2974): [v1.8] RemoteMediaPlayer::onMetadataUpdated() is reached
>
> D/ccl_VideoCastManager(2974): [v1.8] onRemoteMediaPlayerMetadataUpdated() reached

Answer (score 0):

If you are already connected and have launched the application successfully (I presume you see your application on the TV), then the fact that you are using a MediaRouteButton instead of an action provider is irrelevant; the two alternatives (button vs action provider) give you a route and you are passed that stage so don't focus on that if you are trying to solve your current issue.

I also presume you meant loadMedia() rather than loadRemoteMedia(). What do you get as the operation result when you call that? You need to provide more information on that front (definitely include logs).

Comment: Ali, thnx for your reply. I have been reading your answers to various questions on Chromecast integration. Could you plz tell me more specifically what exactly you mean by 'more information' so that I can provide that.

Comment: Let me tell you some of my observations, after clicking chromecast icon it does not turn yellow(selected state), the videoCastControllerActivity does not start, I get value unknown for Media protocol.

Comment: Things that you need to debug on your side: (1) Do you get a device/route or not? (2) If you do, When you try to connect by calling mApi.connect(), does the "onConnected()" callback gets called (i.e. do you really connect to the service?)  Lets establish the answer to these questions first

Comment: Yes, I do get the device route and RouteInfo in onCastDeviceDetected(), In my case onApplicationConnected() is also called in which I call loadRemoteMedia(seekbar position). 
Nowhere in sample app I found calling mApi.connect(), or onConnected() overridden anywhere.

Comment: You keep referring to loadRemoteMedia(seekbar position), what is that? The log you showed is console log, what about sender log?  Are you trying to play HLS media? All the calls in the SDK are asynchronous and all of them return some result asynchronously, you need to check those results to see which one is failing; without real information, there is not much to help you with

Comment: [loadRemoteMedia](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/master/src/com/google/sample/cast/refplayer/mediaplayer/LocalPlayerActivity.java) method can be found at line number 326. I am referring to Cast video sample.

Comment: Does your application load on TV or not?

Comment: If you have time, I would like to invte you to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61458/chromecast-room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61461/discussion-between-ritesh-gune-and-ali-naddaf).

Comment: My question was whether your application loads or not, not asking if video plays or not. Try using CastVideos-android app and take that as your starting point and gradually modify that to meet your needs and test each change you make to make sure you catch any issues quickly.

Comment: See, on selecting the cast device my application is launched. I was just providing you more information that video does not start and I get the above logs on consol.

Comment: (1) Update your CCL to the latest version which is 1.10; you are using 1.8
(2) Follow my recommendation on starting from CastVideos-android and working your way up from there toward your own app